Invoke a workflow in VSCode logic apps
I have 2 workflows where I need to call few details from workflow A to workflow B. I used invoke workflow action added the workflow B name and added the details I need in the body of this. I need the details in the post http of WFB, But I don't see anything in workflow B, can I access details in workflow B in this way?
-Thanks

Yes, you can get the details from workflow A in workflow B. I am able to do so in below way.
Workflow A-
You need to the values in the body of Response action.

Workflow B-

Output-

